# Query multiple tables in KDB

Tags: database, kdb

I want to query multiple tables in KDB.  For ex. how to write following  SQL query in KDB (I am not good at SQL so query format might be wrong):

```
select from table1,table2 where table1.sym=table2.sym and table1.price>table2.price
```

I know some ways of doing it, for ex. joins. But is there any functionality in KDB same as SQL which does it simply using dot notation on tables.

Also in SQL, we can extend above query to 'n' number of tables and filters. Can we do that in  KDB without making a complex expression?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is No I'm afraid.

You can only query 1 table at a time. You have to do the join first. I don't know SQL well but I'm sure the SQL engine is doing a join operation under the hood anyway to be able to do this (?) so if there was a way to do this in `q` via a function it would be doing a join.

If you want extract column vectors you can just index into a table like this (avoid dot notation inside functions):

```
table[`sym]
```

(would get the sym column as a vector, assuming table isn't keyed)
(NB Be careful when doing this on a splayed table!)

You can use that for `in` queries in the where clause, for example. Or if your tables are exactly the same length you can use that to create a new temporary interim table (but that's still a join of a kind!)

That's as close as you're going to get without using the usual `,`, `lj`, `uj`, etc

Comment: Using join I can do that. Just wanted to confirm whether there is any simple way like SQL. By looking at your answer, it seems like join is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

No.

SQL is a declarative language. Your query tells the database *what you want*, not *how to do it*.  The SQL optimizer examines your query, comes up with a tree of operators, estimates the cost of performing each operation, and attempts to re-order the tree to minimize the total cost.

Q does not have a database optimizer except the one sitting at the keyboard.  You have to determine the order of operations, and you have to perform them in the correct order.

Additionally, Q operates on columns, not on rows.  So `table1.price>table2.price` doesn't make sense unless table1 and table2 are exactly the same length.  Usually people handle this by renaming the second column, performing the join, and then filtering the resulting single table.